# Swift (Xcode) REST API Connection using OAuth 1

Tags: ios, xcode, rest, api, oauth

Quick background, I am extremely new in this realm. I am aware that this type of question has been asked before and answered successfully. The issue that I am experiencing is caused by the inability to wrap my head around the process of establishing the connection. I have spent hours (into days) searching for the answer and I am still unsuccessful. This has become my "white whale" so to speak.

I am using Xcode 9 with Swift version 4. Many of the answer I come across use Objective-C and I cannot mix and match. So I would like to UNDERSTAND why I am unable to connect and the correct process to connect so I can write the code with the understanding of what I am doing. Lastly, I have signed up (and completed) a few paid Udemy courses to try and learn the process correctly. I have been able to connect to API sources but OAuth 1 is tripping me up. Any constructive help would be incredibly appreciated.

Background:

I am attempting to connect to the Fat Secret database. I would like to connect a search bar to the food.search functionality and also the food.get for another search bar.

Company- *FatSecret*
URL for API- *platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api*
URL to FatSecret documentation (I have gone through this MANY times)- *http:// {space} platform.fatsecret. {space }com/api/Default. {space} aspx?screen=rapiauth*
Parameters- Parameters {
*oauth_consumer_key* - *consumer_key (I have a consumer key)*
*oauth_signature_method* - *"HMAC-SHA1"*
*oauth_timestamp* - *The date and time, expressed in the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. The timestamp value must be a positive integer and must be equal or greater than the timestamp used in previous requests*
*oauth_nonce* - A randomly generated string for a request that can be combined with the timestamp to produce a unique value
*oauth_version* - Must be "1.0"
}

As I previously stated, the answer to my question is displayed above. I understand that part but I do not understand how to incorporate it into my code.

Past code-

```
        let url = URL(string: "I am unable to post more than 2 links due to my rep so I put {space} in the above url to circumvent the error. I used the listed url from the parameters")!


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

           if error != nil { print("success")

   }    task.resume()
```

The above code is what I used to establish the connection. I receive "success" in the console so I expanded my parameters.

```
    let url = URL(string: "I am unable to post more than 2 links due to my rep so I put {space} in the above url to circumvent the error. I used the listed url from the parameters")!


                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
                            (data, response, error) in

                           if error != nil { print(error)

        if let urlContent = data {

                            do {

                           let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

print(jsonResult)

    } catch {




               }    task.resume()
```

The above code produces nothing in the console. I believe (sorry for my ignorance) that the reason I am not getting a response is because I am not sending any authorization in the request, nor am I am sending in the correct encoding. I imagine that I can create the parameters by var/let statements and then call on those statements but I am not able to see the way to do that. I could likely also store all of my connection information in a different swift file or class and call on that when I need to access data. This base signature is required with every request. I have to imagine that best practice would be setting it up that way but again, I can't visualization the process. It becomes a trial and error process that results in incredible frustration.

Again, any help would be incredibly appreciated. I apologize for the length of this post. Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

Comment: You do `print(jsonResult)` inside the `catch`?

Comment: my apologies, I do that higher in the code. I was copying the code from two separate documents.  I would print(jsonResult) above the } catch { line.

Comment: I know this is something that I am doing wrong. I just can't seem to wrap my head around the process. It could be as simple as not setting up the correct values in a class. I have tried a multitude of things and I can't seem to connect. The closest I got was connecting correctly but it was connecting to the HTML variant of the site. I could go through WKWebView but I would prefer through API with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be late but I have successfully managed to implement the FatSecret REST API and have created a small Xcode project that shows how I handled OAuth. The only calls that can be made are food.search and food.get. https://github.com/NicholasBellucci/FatSecretSwift